# Unity does not use the categories from the .desktop files

Tags: unity, edubuntu

I installed the educational version of Ubuntu with Unity.  This is for kids.  The most important applications are the ones that the descriptions says are specially added for kids.  Trying to find them is a pain in the applications directory.  They are organized in the main menu, but Unity does not use the main menu information for anything.

Bottom line, I am now going to reinstall Ubuntu and NOT include Unity.  The panels feature is nice, but there needs to some ability to organize the applications -- either with a menu or a directory structure that is read.  The .desktop files indicate categories ... like education.  Why does Unity not use this information?

Comment: Can you just log into the classic desktop?

Answer (score 2):

If you run all the latest components of the Unity stack (specifically unity-place-applications >= 0.2.38) you'll see that it now respects the same categories as found in the Software Center  (if you click the dropdown next to the search entry you should hopefully see what I mean).

As for adding special emphasis on the educational apps in Edubuntu - that's certainly an option, I just don't think the Edubuntu team has had the time to keep on top of the rapid changes coming in for Unity.